# javascript- Wait till function finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, chatbot

I'm building a chatbot. Some example of the chat scripts are as follows:

```
var convpatterns = new Array (
  new Array (".*ask me a question*", Question1),
  new Array ("I need (.*)" , "Why do you need $1?" , "Are you sure you need $1?"),
  new Array (".*sorry.*", "Please dont apologise", "Apologies are not necessary", "it is ok, it didn't bother me")
);
```

So basically if the user types "ask me a question", it will direct the user to the `Question1()` function. And if the user types "I need a friend", the chatbot will reply by asking "why do you need a friend?" or "Are you sure you need a friend?".

```
function Question1(){        
  var textbox=document.getElementById("messages").value;
  window.iSpeech.speak(speakPluginResultHandler,nativePluginErrorHandler,"Do you smoke?");

  if (textbox="Yes"){
    window.iSpeech.speak(speakPluginResultHandler,nativePluginErrorHandler,"Oh, do you know smoking is bad for your health?");
  } else if (textbox="No"){
    window.iSpeech.speak(speakPluginResultHandler,nativePluginErrorHandler,"That's great to hear that you don't smoke!");
  }
}
```

The `window.ispeech.speak` will allow the chatbot to verbally speak the words.

So when the chatbot asks the question, "Do you smoke?", and the user types either "yes" or "no" in the textbox, the chatbot then responds based on the reply.

What I want is for the `Question1()` function to finish running before the chatbot goes about and asks other things (so it waits for the user to type either "yes" or "no" before the function can be finished and a new script can begin), as I don't want the user's response to clash with the other scripts available in the arrays (e.g. the input "yes" to the textbox might clash with another "Yes" array in the script).

Answer (score 0):

You actually need something like a **state machine**. But can always hold the current -let's say- command in a variable. Then you always check for the command to be finished. As long as a current command is not set to null(means no current command) you can not listen to another command. Each of you command should have at least one final state. It can be a value that will be entered by user. When the final state condition(s) of current command were meet you can set it to null.

Comment: Can I use a Callback function to make it work? As I'm not familiar with state machine.

Comment: It doesn't matter where to save current command variable ( in server to access it with callback or in client), that's up to you.